# Variable Fan Controller - Properly Sized Transistor

Tags: current, transistor

I would like to a build a temperature sensing variable speed fan controller for my truck. Currently using a purchased 2 speed on/off relay based controller, but my fans are overloading the whole circuit when the controller is powered on during a high speed temperature scenario. On low speed, I have the fans wired in series to spin both slower - works great. Each fan initially draws 100 amps at full 12v. On the low speed (6v/series), they cruise about 20a together. On high speed, they settle in around 25a each.

I am somewhat experienced with arduino and using a few references to build in specific features I want, but here is the main example I am going by.
https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/automatic-temperature-controlled-fan-project

My question is around the type and size of transistor that I would need to handle the amount of current these fans draw. Some examples have MOSFET while others have FET or even standard PNP. I am pretty new to working with transistors and can't find any references that make sense. Would love to get a reference to learn this calculation and appropriate type.

Edit: removed picture with incorrect wiring diagram.

Comment: You would typically have a bank of parallel power MOSFETs with a big heatsink.

Comment: the arduino cannot induce current flow into the base of Q1 because the arduino ground is not connected to the emitter of Q1 ... therefore Q1 will not turn on

Comment: @jsotola I didn't catch that before linking to that picture. Thanks for pointing out, though it's not my question. Removed the picture.

Comment: The easiest might be to use a solid state relay. There are devices for DC and they often can be controlled directly with 3.3V or 5V. In any case, thermal management will play an important role

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick search for high-current MOSFET transistors, I ran across the following:

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ixys/IXFK170N20T/2126313

The important spec here is the Rds ON (max) of 11mOhm @ 60A, 10V

At your peak current of 100A, you would drop 1.1V across the transistor, for a power dissipation of 110W.

The advertised P(max) is 1150W, so assuming the junction temp can be held to under 175C (and with an entire metal truck to use for a heat sink, this shouldn't be a problem) you should be OK with this device.  In the 'cruise' configuration with 25A motor current, you should have no problem controlling the fans.

YMMV ;-)

Comment: Your answer is fine, but as the OP mentioned to have little experience with transistors, I want to add that this mosfet can't be controlled with qn arduino's logic level and needs an additional drive circuit

Comment: Good point - thanks for the addition!